# Linking to css file using asset in laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel, hyperlink, frameworks

Instead of using localhost to access the file, I've used domain name lsapp.com
When I try to link to css file using asset, it links to lsapp.com/css/app.css but doesn't work. Same index.php file in public folder opens while using lsapp.com. 
I've tried many different methods but none worked.Please help.

Currently using this but doesn't work

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But if I use localhost to open the file, css works fine.

```
http://localhost/lsapp/public/index.php
```

Comment: share your current output and your needed output

Comment: which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Have you set application URL in the file config/app.php`'url' => 'http://www.example.com',`

Comment: i' using Laravel version 5.7.9 @V5NXT

Comment: i've set url in config/app.php as 'url' => env( 'http:// www. lsapp.com',  http:// localhost')  @JYoThI

Comment: i tried to include bootstrap css file provided default by laravel using asset but the output was the same like ordinary html file while using lsapp.com but when i use localhost/lsapp/public/index.php the file opens with a background color and font with margins and all present in the css @BhargavChudasama

Answer (score 0):

Laravel using in latest version Ithink that would be more conventional.

```
mix.styles([
    'asset/css/app.css',

]);
```

Please refer :

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/best-way-to-use-custom-css-in-laravel

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix

Comment: i'm sorry but i didn't get the documentation and where to apply this code. @V5NXT

Comment: Its the latest version of laravel you can find it here.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#plain-css

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to watch the free lesson from laracast over laravel-mix.
https://laracasts.com/series/learn-laravel-mix/episodes/1

You will learn a lot about compiling css & js.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your `.env` file set up correctly.

"*i've set url in config/app.php as 'url' => env( 'http:// www. lsapp.com', http:// localhost')*" is wrong.

`env()` takes a variable name from your `.env` file, not an URL. Revert those changes back to the default:

`'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),`

This basically says, "*url is either the value of `APP_URL` from your environment (.env file) or, if that doesn't exist, use [http://localhost](http://localhost_)*"

In your `.env` file, set `APP_URL` to `http://www.lsapp.com`, run `php artisan config:cache` to load and cache the values from `.env` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be work.

Maybe you are assuming that you have your CSS folder inside your public directory, I think you need to require illuminate/html to your project.

Comment: the css file is in the public folder by default. can you elaborate on the require illuminate/html, i didn't quite understand what u meant

Comment: <link href="{{ URL::asset('css/masterCss.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

Or

<link href="/css/master.css" rel="stylesheet">

I don't get it. Why would someone use URL facade for something as simple as this.

Comment: i used both methods but doesn't work. While using asset, it must link to public file. But i thinks its not linking to public file can you help with this